# Mechanical Engineering- Modeling contact in Abaqus

Tags: simulation, rail, numerical-methods, abaqus, mechanical

I have simulated a 2D model in Abaqus which indicates 2 main part, first a sector that represent as wheel and, second a rectangular that represent rail. the wheel and rail are in contact and wheel should rotate and move from left to right. there is a vertical small crack in middle of the rail to studying the result of contact on fracture mechanics. my model has been completed, and in the 1/10 of total time good result has been achieved but after that the stress distribution is completely wrong and although the contact seems to exist, the stress is almost zero. Any guide, comment or advice would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There can be thousands of causes for your error. You need to give many more informations to be able to make a guess.
Like: discretization, solving methods for the DEQs, grid topology, boundary conditions etc.

Comment: Exactly and I can't understand which one it is, what is your suggestion? if it is possible give me your mail to send my model, thank you

Comment: I don't have Abaqus, but I'm working alot with simulations and that sounds like a typical simulation problem. So without additional information it is impossible to help. Since it could be a combination of the above mentioned, please provide as much information as possible.